# Appending character to variable in execute query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to execute a dynamic SQL statement, which searches for names whose last name is always a constant and first name is a variable.
Here is a query I have written for selecting a row with name='Test lastname'.

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT name FROM users 
        WHERE name=$1 lastname'
USING ('Test');
```

This generates a syntax error. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What you mean when say "constant"?  Hard coded value ?

Comment: to debug: store your sql to a variable and write out the variable so you can see what was built.

Comment: @OtoShavadze yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT user_id FROM users 
        WHERE name=$1'
USING  Test||' lastname' ;
```

Here `Test` is variable and 'lastname' is hard coded value

Also another way is as @JorgeCampos mentioned:

```
...WHERE name=$1 || '' lastname''' USING 'Test';
```

Comment: Almost... since lastname seems to be a column from the users table I think he wants: `...WHERE  name=$1 || lastname' USING 'Test '`

Comment: @JorgeCampos - As I understand, he have only `name` column and stores both first  and last names there

Comment: I want rows with name = 'Test  lastname'  where the last name is always 'lastname' and first name is a variable.

Comment: @JabirMohammed - and `Test` is variable ?

Comment: I want names that end with 'lastname' and first name as an input from the user.

Comment: Then he needs: `...WHERE name=$1 || '' lastname''' USING 'Test';` if lastname is constant and a text

Comment: @JabirMohammed - I edited answer, may be that is what you need?

Comment: @Jorge Campos - ..WHERE name=$1 || '' lastname''' USING 'Test'; That's what i needed. Thanks man!

Comment: @JabirMohammed You are welcome... glad to help. Oto, please edit your answer with it so Jabir can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - Thank you very much for collaborating, may be better to answer you as your own answer because it's unfair to use your code =) (because actually it is whole answer, not only snippet). Though, I don't get what is difference between our variants? It seems only syntax, content seems same...

Comment: There is no difference as of now. By the time he asked your answer was still with the 'Test ' || lastname variation (I think). And since you provide the right way (even though slightly different) I choose just to collaborate with your answer :) cheers

Comment: @JorgeCampos - Ah, I understand now, your comment was before... Thank you again :)